# Understanding ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a ArrayList of Metricas.
Each Metrica has some properties and another ArrayList lForms.
What I want to to is check in the db to see if the form has been filled, and update the lForms.
When I do so, I get a ConcurrentModificationException, I don't know how to get rid of it...

```
public ArrayList<Metrica> addAllForms(ArrayList<Metrica> lMetricas) {
    ArrayList<Metrica> newlMet = lMetricas;
    ArrayList<Formulario> lForms = null;
    ArrayList<Formulario> newlForms;
    Metrica newMetrica;
    Formulario f;
    for (Iterator<Metrica> it = lMetricas.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Metrica metrica = it.next();

        newlForms = new ArrayList<Formulario>();
        lForms = metrica.getlForms();
        for (Iterator<Formulario> it2 = lForms.iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
            Formulario form = it2.next();

            f = getForm(form);
            if (f == null) {
                addForm(form, metrica.getId());
                Log.e("log", "adding form");
            } else
                form = f;
            Log.e("log", "Getting adding form");

            newlForms.add(form);

        }

        newMetrica = new Metrica();
        newMetrica.setlForms(newlForms);
        newMetrica.setClienteId(metrica.getClienteId());
        newMetrica.setDatoValido(metrica.getDatoValido());
        newMetrica.setDescription(metrica.getDescription());
        newMetrica.setId(metrica.getId());
        newMetrica.setProyectoProductoId(metrica.getProyectoProductoId());
        newMetrica.setTipo(metrica.getTipo());

        newlMet.add(newMetrica);

    }

    return lMetricas;
}
```

Comment: I'm not removing anything !

Comment: remove, add, same thing.

Comment: You can't modify the structure of an ArrayList while you're iterating over it... Check out the linked duplicate (adding elements to the list is the same thing as removing them, you're _structurally modifying the list_).

Comment: Ok. I will try using Iterator. Tx

Comment: I used Iterator, and still the same problem. Besides, I'm not adding nothing to the ArrayList lMetricas or lForms... I don't understand !

Comment: You do add to `IMetricas` since `newlMet = lMetricas;` and `newlMet.add(newMetrica);`.

Comment: Upps, the error was that line :   
ArrayList<Metrica> newlMet = new ArrayList<Metrica>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
for (Metrica metrica : lMetricas)
```

Use the following:

```
Iterator<Metrica> it = lMetricas.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    Metrica metrica = it.next();
    //...
}
```

Similarly, you need to do the same ting with the `lForms`.

**Edit:** If you want to add something, you cannot just add them while iterating. Instead, use another `ArrayList` to store the elements you want to add. Afterwards, use `lMetricas.addAll()` to add them all at once.

If you want to add them to specific positions, you need to use a `Map<Metrica, Integer>` and use the values to find which position to add.

Comment: What's different between that `for` loop and that `while` loop?

Comment: Using an iterator while iterating over a list provides the flexibility of modifying the list.

Comment: I updated my code, I'm using Iterator, and still the same exception